# Reference the folder with {{this}} in dbt

Tags: sql, dbt

I know that it's possible to reference the database, schema and tables inside a SQL file/model in dbt. Example:

```
select
    '{{ this }}' as full_path,
    '{{ this.schema }}' as schema_name,
    '{{ this.database }}' as db_name,
    '{{ this.table }}' as table_name
```

However, I was looking for a way to also get the folder where a certain .sql file is inside. In my mind, I'd guess something like this: `{{ this.folder }}`. But unfortunately, It does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a [Relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#relation), which is a reference to an object in your database, not a reference to the Model that produced the Relation (which is a file in your project).

The `graph` context variable contains the path for each model; it used to be hard to access the current model's node programmatically, since it's keyed by the project and model name, but dbt solved that by adding in the `model` variable, which does just that.

`{{ model.path }}` will give you the full path to the model file (relative to the models folder, so `marts/marketing/orders.sql` if your file is in `/models/marts/marketing/orders.sql`).

If you just want the folder, you'll have to munge the `path` a bit:

```sql
{% if execute %}
{% set path = model.path %} -- e.g. 'marts/marketing/orders.sql'
{% set path_list = path.split('/') %} -- e.g. ['marts', 'marketing', 'orders.sql']
{% set folder = path_list[:-1] | join('/') %} -- e.g., 'marts/marketing'
{% endif %}
```

**Update:**
`{{ model.root_path }}` is being removed in v1.4. In prior versions, you could also use `{{ model.root_path }}` for the path to your project root (e.g., `/home/tco/open/jaffle_shop`).

Comment: That's a very interesting answer. Thanks for sharing. I marked it as resolved because that's exactly what I needed. Do you have any idea of how could I wrap the folder variable to pass it in the {{config(...)}} file? I was trying with alias={{'folder'}}, but it does not work.

Comment: Don't nest your curlies. `{{ config(alias=folder) }}` will work (if you set `folder` first, above the `config` call in your file). See: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies